# Duplicated Xcode project issue

Tags: xcode

I've duplicated my Xcode project - basically I'm creating an app with similar functionality but with different content. I duplicated the main folder and updated the names in the new project for the new app following a guide on Youtube that was on another thread, but when I updated the background of the storyboard for the new app, I've now seen it has changed the storyboard of the original app, so it must be using the same story file, or be linked somehow.
Please can someone suggest what I might have done wrong, or what I need to do when duplicating the project to avoid the same story file being used.

Comment: If the modification are "minors", it may be more interesting to duplicate the target rather than duplicate the project. That way, if you fix something on the first target, the second one may benefits from it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the "Full path" of your file like shown below. Make also sure, that all your other files are linked correctly.
[image]

Comment: No problem ay :) may you please mark it as the correct answer?